# Refresh Container/Screen with useState AND map() in React Native

Tags: react-native, use-state

in my application, after receiving the updated data from the API I use useState, but this does not reflect on the information on the screen, I need to goBack and forward to change the information.

When I click on the button I save the information and on the return I need to update that the task has already been done, showing an "OK", but this is not updated, even though the "schedules" variable is right.

Where am I going wrong? What do I need to do to "return" and run again?

Thanks a lot!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
...

const Pdvs = () => {
  const [scheduletasks, setScheduletasks] = useState([]);
...

onSave = async (id) => {.....
 const responseTask = await api.post("/schedules/fulldetails",{id});
      setScheduletasks(responseTask.data);
...

return (
    <Container>
        {scheduletasks.map((keys) => (
              {keys.done ? "OK"
              ) : ""}
        <Button title="Done"
                onPress={() =>
                  handleSave(keys.id)
                }
              />
```

Comment: Seems like the return value in the map callback is not right. You are literally returning {"string"}.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes a little broken, especially in `return()`. Please revise it to get better help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I put just a piece of the code, to filter where is not the problem. Below more compleat code:

My "onSubmit" should be where you update the variable for useState

The big problem is in the Return, variable {keys.done}, is just that I want! :)
Thanks a lot

```
 onSubmit = async (inputText) => {
    try {
      const { schedule_id, product_id, task_id } = scheduletasksResult;
      const gpsPosition = await getLocationAsync();

      const response = await api.post(`/scheduletasks/add`, {
        schedule_id,
        product_id,
        task_id,
        result: inputText,
        gpsPosition,
      });

      if (response.status === 200) {
        setScheduletasksID(response.data.id);
      } else {
        setScheduletasksID(0);
      }
      return response.data.id;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
    }
  };
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function loadPdvs() {
      setCompany_id(company_id[1]);

      const response = await api.post("/schedules", {
        company_id: company_id[1],
        id,
      });
      setSchedules(response.data[0]);

      const responseTask = await api.post("/schedules/fulldetails", {
        company_id: company_id[1],
        id,
      });
      setScheduletasks(responseTask.data);
    }
    loadPdvs();
  }, []);
```

```
return (
    <Container>
      <RouteTitle>{schedules.tradeName}</RouteTitle>
      <ScrollView>
        {scheduletasks.map((keys) => (
          <RoutesContainer key={keys.task_id}>
            <RouteDetail>
              {keys.task_name}
              {keys.done ? (
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                  icon={faCheckCircle}
                />
              ) : null}
            </RouteDetail>
            {keys.textRequired ? (
              <Button
                title="Observações"
                onPress={() =>
                  showDialog(keys.schedule_id, keys.product_id, keys.task_id)
                }
              />
            ) : null}
          </RoutesContainer>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </Container>
  );
```